# How to execute python manage.py django management command via button on the website on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, executable, django-commands

I have a Django management commands that I would like to run. I would like to have it available for a user by clicking the button and it would execute it. I do not need help to write one - I have them working, but always I need to run them from the terminal like:

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdata
```

Very convenient would be to just click the button on the running production website and it would start it for me. How can I make this happen on the site running on Heroku?

As a simple example:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from project.models import Video

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Sync Movie / Plays'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        uri_video = Video.objects.all()
        for item in uri_video:
            item.update(title=item.title.capitalize())

        print "Done."
```

It is just updating the title which not important.

Comment: The `handle()` function of your management command is nothing else than a python function that you can call from anywhere. So just build a view that calls it and your button could have a javascript calling that view using ajax, returning if it succeeded or not.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have added a small example of the django command. Can you show a simple example code how to call it in the view and if possible with a small javascript / ajax the return?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a bit to the comment by [dirkgroten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252711/dirkgroten), you can create a view that calls the below functionality and have it called asynchronously using ajax.

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command("syncdata")
```

Comment: Have added a comment to @dirkgroten's answer - would you be able to show a little  example how to accomplish this?